# FancyBox JS stopped working on multiple sites. Custom plugin responsible. Urgent help needed

Tags: plugins, jquery

First post here so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

The company I work for uses a custom FancyBox Wordpress plugin that allows us to use fancy box on images easily. Basically, when you click on the image it expands to fill the center of the screen. Standard stuff, however we're having a problem.

Since last week or so it has stopped working and the images just link to themselves (takes you to a new page with he image on a white background). This isn't ideal for obvious reasons, and the developer isn't in the country for the foreseeable future so I can't ask him to fix it.

I've looked through the plugin files and the source code for the pages that are output, and the javascript isn't being called properly. It looks like this in the page source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery.wpxFancybox();</script>
```

The main plugin file responsible for this output appears to be [this](http://pastebin.com/v0MCU8A5) (paste bin link).

I'm alright with PHP but this is beyond me. I would really appreciate your help with this problem.

Let me know if you require the code from any other files in the plugin. I'll be happy to supply them.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: This looks like a Javascript Error. Did you check the Console on your Browser to see if any Errors occur?

Comment: Ah! Just checked and it says [this](http://pastebin.com/63Rdt38S).

Comment: Did you also update your WordPress installation or any other Plugins? Can you please post a link to the Site?

Comment: The site is http://www.lguess.co.uk/. It's been updated to WP 3.5 recently, but I couldn't tell you if any plugins have been updated, I don't have a record of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you include jQuery 1.9, in which the jQuery.browser was removed. Look at your `functions.php`, you will find a line in there saying `wp_register_script` or `wp_enqueue_script` with the parameter 'jquery'.

The URL you are loading jQuery from is 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', and you have to change it to 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js'.

Please ask your developer to update your Fancyboxscript when he returns to your country :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed it myself (Im good with HTML & CSS, and learning PHP). It was in the header file. Changed the URL and it fixed it. I really appreciate you helo fischi, thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. You should really ask your developer to stick to the WordPress way of including scripts and files here, so you are much safer regarding such issues. Have a nice time!

Comment: How would it work the Wordpress way? He's left for NZ for possibly a year, so I'm taking over any small scale development. What would you recommend as a way to include it? (If you have time to answer that is!) I appreciate your time :)

Comment: Look into [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), and use `wp_head` in your `header.php`. Get a little used to this - and do not try this stuff on your live website ;) Be Part of the community, and it will work out fine with the time. We are here to help if you are stuck :)

Comment: Ah yes I see. I've used that before. I'll look into it further. Still have lots to learn. Thanks again for the help, I really appreciate it.